# Designing a DFA for binary strings having 1 as the fourth character from the end

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

I came across someone else's old post here

[Designing a DFA that accepts strings such that nth character from last satisfies condition](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14008/designing-a-dfa-that-accepts-strings-such-that-nth-character-from-last-satisfies)

And decided to try it. Apparently it was a homework problem but it was from 2013 so I assume it is okay to discuss it openly by now.

The problem is:

> Design a DFA that accepts strings having 1 as the 4th character from
>   the end, on the alphabet {0,1}

The regular expression that does this I believe is `(0|1)*1(000|001|010|011|100|101|110|111)`.

My NFA:

[image]

Used Google to see how DFAs work and tried this translation:

[image]

Was this a valid solution to the problem?

(Blue arrow = points to starting state, green states are accepting states)

Comment: Welcome! 1) Please take care to pick more descriptive titles. "A DFA problem" describes every other question tagged [tag:finite-automata], so please be more specific. 2) "Check-my-answer" questions are not what this platform works best for. Why are you having doubts? What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not created a DFA.

What you have created is a second slightly less messy NFA. (Sort of; as mentioned in comments elsewhere you need the explosion of internal states out from (2) that you have out from (9) in the original NFA)

So let's pretend that we have an NFA that is made by chopping off state (2) in the second picture and adding state (9) from the first picture in its place.

Now, let's walk through the powerset construction on that new NFA:

Start in state `{1}`. So let's call the DFA state corresponding to the singleton set `{1}`, `DFA_1`.

From `DFA_1` you can see either a `0` or a `1`. On `0`, `DFA_1` goes to `{1}`, so `DFA_1` again. On `1`, it goes to `{1,9}`. Call that `DFA_2`.

From `DFA_2`, on `0` it goes to `{1,10,13,16,19}`. Call that `DFA_3`. On `1` it goes to `{1,9,22,25,28,31}`. Call that `DFA_4`.

For `DFA_3`, on `0` it goes to `{1,11,14}` (since the other nodes only have transitions out on `1`). Call that `DFA_5`. On `1`, from `DFA_3` we go to `{1,9,17,20}`. Call that `DFA_6`.

For `DFA_4`, on `0` it goes to `{1,10,13,16,19,23,26}` - call that `DFA_7`. On `1`, `DFA_4` goes to `{1,9,22,25,28,29,31,32}`. Call that `DFA_8`.

For `DFA_5`, on `0` it goes to `{1,12}`. Call that `DFA_9`. Note that `DFA_9` is an accepting state. On `1` it goes to `{1,9,15}`. Call this `DFA_10`, also an accepting state.

For `DFA_6`, on `0` it goes to `{1,10,13,16,18,19}`. Call this `DFA_11`. On `1`, we get `{1,9,21,22,25,28,31}`. Call this `DFA_12`. Note that `DFA_11` and `DFA_12` are accepting states.

For `DFA_7`, on `0` it goes to `{1,11,14,24}`. Call that `DFA_13`. On `1`, we get `{1,9,17,20,27}`. Call that `DFA_14`. (DFA states 13 and 14 are accepting states)

For `DFA_8`, on `0` it goes to `{1,10,13,16,19,23,26,30}`. Call that `DFA_15`. On `1`, it goes to `{1,9,22,25,28,29,31,32,33}`. Call that `DFA_16`. (DFA states 15 and 16 are accepting states)

For `DFA_9`, on `0` it goes to `{1}`. We've seen this before! That's `DFA_1`. On `1` it goes to `{1,9}`, which is `DFA_2`.

For `DFA_10`, on `0` it goes to `{1,10,13,16,19}`, that is, `DFA_3`. On `1` it goes to `{1,9,22,25,28,31}`, that is `DFA_4`.

For `DFA_11`, on `0` it goes to `{1,11,14}`, which is `DFA_5`. On `1` it goes to `{1,9,17,20}`, that is, `DFA_6`.

For `DFA_12`, on `0` it goes to `{1,10,13,16,19,23,26}`, or `DFA_7`. On `1`, it goes to `{1,9,22,25,28,29,31,32}`, or `DFA_8`.

For `DFA_13`, on `0` it goes to `{1,12}` (`DFA_9`). On `1` it goes to `{1,9,15}` (`DFA_10`).

For `DFA_14`, on `0` it goes to `{1,10,13,16,18,19}` (`DFA_11`). On `1`, we get `{1,9,21,22,25,28,31}` (`DFA_12`)

For `DFA_15`, on `0` it goes to `{1,11,14,24}` (`DFA_13`) On `1`, we get `{1,9,17,20,27}` (`DFA_14`).

For `DFA_16`, I hope you can see the pattern by now. On `0` it goes to `DFA_15` and on `1` to `DFA_16`.

So, in summary:

```
DFA state #  |   Next for 0  |  Next for 1  |  Accepting?
---------------------------------------------------------
          1  |       1       |      2       |
          2  |       3       |      4       |
          3  |       5       |      6       |
          4  |       7       |      8       |
          5  |       9       |     10       |
          6  |      11       |     12       |
          7  |      13       |     14       |
          8  |      15       |     16       |
          9  |       1       |      2       |  yes
         10  |       3       |      4       |  yes
         11  |       5       |      6       |  yes
         12  |       7       |      8       |  yes
         13  |       9       |     10       |  yes
         14  |      11       |     12       |  yes
         15  |      13       |     14       |  yes
         16  |      15       |     16       |  yes
```

As a side note, I think this process might have been simpler had you started with an NFA of only 5 states corresponding to the regex `(0|1)*1((0|1)(0|1)(0|1))`.

(Though you'd still end up needing 16 DFA states - it can be proven that that's the minimal number of DFA states needed for this problem)

Answer (score 1):

No.  The problem statement asks for a DFA.  Your solution isn't a DFA; it's a NFA.  For instance, it has two transitions out of the start state on the symbol 1.  So, this is not a valid solution.

Comment: FWIW, the automaton seems to be a correct NFA at least, so applying the powerset construction will lead to a correct DFA.

Comment: @Raphael seeing the automaton as an NFA requires that we allow multiple-characters-at-once-transitions along the edges, though. The classical NFA definition doesn't allow this, so more states would be needed to get rid to this "feature".

Comment: @DCTLib Yup, that's an easily remedied formality. It's abundantly clear what these edges mean, and from the first image it's clear that the OP knows as well. (For drawing purposes, I actually prefer compacted edges since it makes the image more clear!)