# How do I draw a DFA diagram when I only care about how the string ends?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Hi so this is my first week learning about automata and I have an exercise I'm going through. I'm supposed to draw a diagram for the DFA that accepts all strings of a and b where the third last symbol is a b. 
So it's like : $\{a,b\}^*b\{a,b\}^2$ right?

And if I would draw it I would do this to check the end:
[image]

I believe this to be correct but I'm not sure how to draw the possibilites of a's and b's beforehand

Comment: It is incorrect. Consider $bbbb$. If you are looking for the correct DFA, does [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/40828/83244) solve your problem?

Comment: @xskxzr ah that's right... No I don't really understand the answer at that link and it doesn't look familiar to anything I find in the chapters of the course book.

Comment: There are some hints for this problem in [Designing a DFA that accepts strings such that nth character from last satisfies condition](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14008/designing-a-dfa-that-accepts-strings-such-that-nth-character-from-last-satisfies/52299).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Designing a DFA that accepts strings such that nth character from last satisfies condition](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14008/designing-a-dfa-that-accepts-strings-such-that-nth-character-from-last-satisfies)